# Preventing customers from entering price from overriding all other prices in NopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am having an issue in NOPCommerce where when a product price is set to customer enters price that price over rides all other prices such as; attributes, base cost etc.

I am using nopcommerce 3.0 source

I am using a gift card system where as there will be a base cost for the plastic of the cards and the value entered will be gift card value entered by the customer will be the gift card value, so these 2 values will need to added together

I have tried multiple steps in the admin to try and add a base cost but had no result,

I have looked through the code and found this but unsure what to change or if it is even this controller I need to edit etc.

**PriceCalculationServices.cs**

```
 if (productVariant.CustomerEntersPrice)
 {
      finalPrice = shoppingCartItem.CustomerEnteredPrice;
 }
 else
 {
      finalPrice = GetFinalPrice(productVariant,
           customer,
           attributesTotalPrice,
           includeDiscounts,
           shoppingCartItem.Quantity);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now fixed,

i amended the above code to:

```
  if (productVariant.CustomerEntersPrice)
                {
                    finalPrice = shoppingCartItem.CustomerEnteredPrice + productVariant.ProductCost;
                }
```

it now adds whatever i set the product cost to in admin to the value the customer enters :)